# Laravel 5.2 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 Error

Tags: php, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I am following tuts+ video series for developing an ecommerce web app. I am almost done with it but I got one problem in the store section. I am displaying list of all products on `/store` route to the end users and I did that BUT now what I want to establish is single view page for each product.In simple words when I am on Store Page with all the products displayed , I want each product linked with his own singlepage view i.e price, picture , and other data about that specific post. I followed the video but when I try to access single page of a product it throws the following error.

**Error:**

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 823
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('D:\xampp\htdocs\ecom\public\index.php') in index.php line 21
```

**Store index file on which all products or displayed**:

```
    @foreach($products as $product)
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                                <li>{!! $product->title  !!} - ({!! $product->price !!})</li>
                                <p> {!! $product->description !!}</p>
                                <a href="store/view/{!! $product->id !!}">
                                    {!! Html::image($product->image ,$product->title) !!}</p>
                                </a>        
                              {!! Form::close() !!}
                         </div>
   @endforeach
```

**View.blade.php  or single page for product:**

```
{!! $product->title !!} <br>
{!! $product->description !!} <br>
{!! $product->image !!}
```

**StoreController Code :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Category;
use App\product;
use View;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class StoreController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('store.index')->with('products', product::take(4)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('InsertCategory');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
            $category = new Category;
            $category->name = Input::get('name');
            $category->save();      
            return Redirect::to('admin/categories')->with('message', 'Category Created');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return View::make('store.view')->with('product', product::find($id));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $category = Category::find(Input::get('id'));
        var_dump($input);
        if($category){
            $category->delete();
            return Redirect::to('admin/categories');
        }
    }
}
```

Routes.php :

```
Route::get('/', 'StoreController@index');
Route::get('/admin', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::resource('store', 'StoreController');
Route::resource('admin/categories', 'CategoriesController');
Route::resource('admin/products', 'ProductsController');
```

PS : If you people need any thing more just mention in comment I will add that.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ELxNgow.jpg

Comment: @iam-decoder ahahaha why so serious? Is this offensive ?

Comment: as i've observed you're not calling any of your methods while calling you're controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your store index blade, you're not using a relative link, so it's attaching `store/view/{!! $product->id !!}` to whatever the current url (without QS) is.

if you add a `/` to the beginning of that href it might solve your problem. It also looks like you don't have a `view` method in your store controller, try changing that to `show`

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
        <li>{!! $product->title  !!} - ({!! $product->price !!})</li>
        <p> {!! $product->description !!}</p>
        <a href="/store/{!! $product->id !!}">
            {!! Html::image($product->image ,$product->title) !!}
        </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @LaravelWarrior when you click on a product, what is the current url address?

Comment: @LaravelWarrior you don't have a `view` method in your controller, try changing that to `show`?

Comment: I changed view.blade.php to show.blade.php and in controller return to store.show , and the url to store/show/ {!! $product->id !!} still same error

Comment: @LaravelWarrior I'm assuming your new url is `localhost/ecom/store/show/12`. It needs to be `localhost/ecom/store/12` so actually just remove the word "show" from the href. I've edited my answer for you

Comment: Yes it worked like a charm.But why you have removed show from URL , if you can explain a little it would be great!

Comment: @LaravelWarrior if you go to the `Actions Handled By Resource Controller` section in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers) it shows how urls are translated into their respective methods when using route resources. since you didn't define `/store/view/{$id}` as a specific route, it fell back to the resource controller, which couldn't place the correct controller/method.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is simple to reproduce if you misspell the route name:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php
```

Looks like there is no such route.

try

```
php artisan route:list
```

The problem is likely you misspelled the route name.
It may be `aricles` instead of `articles` and things like that.

Answer (score -1):

It's because you're not calling the method/function that your going to execute. fore example on your "`StoreController` " you are going to execute your `Index`
you should call it to your `routes.php`

like this

```
Route::resource('store', 'StoreController@index');
```

Comment: @Felix Kamote tried that but still not working and by the way it is resource controller we don't need to specify a function like controller@func bcz it automatically do that for us.